# The use of the verb "put" in context

Tags: word-choice

Is the following use of the verb *put* natural.

> The music is aweful. Can I **put** mine?

Would the phrasal verb *turn on* sound better?

Answer (score 2):

I think "Can I put mine?" in the suggested context is not just unnatural, but meaningless. I suppose it might be short for "Can I put mine **on**?" or some similar phrase. I think "Can I turn mine on?" or "Can I play mine instead?" would be much better.

Comment: This might also make more sense if you change the first sentence to contrast *your music* with *the other music*, e.g., "*This* music is awful."

Comment: Can I say "Can I put on mine"?

Comment: "Can I put on mine" is slightly less clear, but a native speaker would understand what you meant, even if it sounded a little odd. To me, "Can I put on mine" is more often used with clothing (e.g., "Can I put on my shirt?") or something else which a person can put onto themselves. "Can I put mine on?" emphasizes that you're doing the action of *putting* to something else.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, I like "This music is awful. Can I play mine instead?" the best. You could also say "This music is awful. Can I play *some* instead?", which sounds more casual to me.